# Excel - Plot time slots on a continuous time axis

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, excel-charts

Let's say we have time slots documented in which a production line was running. In between each product maufactured are time slots in which the machine was idling.
I now want to plot the machine status over time, basically as a boolean value (running vs idling).

[image: I get the machine log and need the chart on the right]
I get the machine log and need the chart on the right.

The machining duration will ultimately be logged including seconds and may vary for each product.

The first - and probably biggest - challenge for me is to find a smart way to extract the status from the time stamps. My current first step ist to create a table row for each minute and use the if statement in H4 to check wether article 1 was being manufactured.
`IF(AND([@Time]>Machine_log[@Start],[@Time]<Machine_log[@Finish]);;)`

However, since the final list will range over 24 hours or more and the number of articles quickly reaches 50 and more, I would love to avoid using nested IFs on this one..

I'm thankfull for any input and open for inspiration :)
Thank you all in advance!

PS: Anyone know how a better way than a scatter chart  with two values per X-Value to display the chart as vertical lines/right angles [like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgV8v.png)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add only those points that are necessary to the Status extraction table (which I named "Status"). (I named the Machine log table "Log").

*Note: it looks like you are using a semicolon list separator, so you'll need to change the commas in the formulas below to semicolons.*

Formula for the `Time` column:

```
=IF(ROW()=ROW(Status),MIN(Log[Start])-1/144,IFERROR(INDEX(Log[[Start]:[Finish]],INT((ROW()-ROW(Status)-1)/4)+1,MOD(INT((ROW()-ROW(Status)-1)/2),2)+1),MAX(Log[Finish])+1/144))
```

Formula for the `Production running?` column (enter into `H4` and fill down):

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(Log[[Start]:[Finish]]=[@Time])),IF([@Time]=G3,3-H3,H3),1)
```

These formulas will pad your plot with 10 minutes of off time on either side.

To answer your question about avoiding two points for each x-value: no, each point on the plot has to have a corresponding data pair.

**UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT:** I failed to mention that the above solution assumes the time data in the Machine log table are in ascending order. This means that if your data span more than one day, they will need to contain a date component or you can get plots where the line crosses back to the beginning. For example, if you have 23:57:00 followed by 00:10:00 with no date component, Excel treats these as 11:57 pm on 1 January 1900 and 12:10 am on 1 January 1900. (To see this, change the format to "General", and you'll see the values that Excel uses to encode date-time aren't in ascending order.) The solution is to enter the dates as "8/16/2020 23:57:00" and "8/17/2020 00:10:00" in the formula bar. If you're copying over from another data source, the date needs to be copied with the time. If the dates and times are in separate columns, your Start and Finish columns would each be a date column plus a time column.

Comment: Got me, I thought I had changed all the semicolons to commas..
With the data above this works like a charm and looks gorgeous, so thank you so much already! However, if I change the data to cover a wider time span or even go past midnight, the graph goes crazy ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNmK7.png ).
The boys downstairs are doing night shifts quite often, so I need a way to include that.
I was looking into your formula hoping to adjust it accordingly.. 
Turns out I can just barely wrap my head around how it's working. So hats off to you and that brain of yours.

Comment: @Dom I believe the problem is a missing date component in your data. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hey @jblood94, thanks for the addition and sorry for my late reply. So as it turns out, the chart seems to work but gets unreadable quickly as I scale this up for a full day.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvLR7.png
I also only now realized my question is missing a critical point: the goal is to see when the machine is idling longer than it should be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyD68.png
So the boolean value should only be 1 when the machine idles longer than a specified "tolerated pause" (here J4). This way I know there was a problem with the process every time the chart hits 1.
Thanks again!

Comment: Also: Is there a way to change the values (1=idle, 2=running) to (0=idle, 1=running)? I tried to adjust the formula, only resulting in messed up results :(

Comment: Ok I think I got it now ranging from 0 to 1:
 
`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(Log[[Start]:[Finish]]=[@Time])),IF([@Time]=G3,1-H3,H3),0)`